# Tailwind CSS autocomplete inside Twig variables

Tags: visual-studio-code, drupal, twig, tailwind-css

I am using TailwindCSS with TWIG files. The purgecss works fine inside CSS files and also inside "normal" markup like

```
<div class="font-bold text-blue"></div>
```

But we are developing mostly Drupal TWIG templates and a lot of our TWIG files setting classes to an attributes array. And the bellow doesn't work.

```
attributes.addClass(['font-bold', 'bg-blue']);
```

or

```
{% set classes = ['font-bold', color == 'blue' ? 'bg-blue'] %}
```

This is my purgecss configuration:

gulp.task(
"styles",
gulp.series("sass", function () {
const postcssimport = require("postcss-import");

```
return gulp
  .src("src/styles.css")
  .pipe(sass().on("error", sass.logError))
  .pipe(
    postcss([
      postcssimport(),
      tailwindcss("./tailwind.config.js"),
      autoprefixer,
    ])
  )
  .pipe(
    purgecss({
      mode: "layers",
      content: ["templates/**/*.twig", "src/scss/**/*.scss"],
      defaultExtractor: (content) => content.match(/[\w-/:]+(?<!:)/g) || [],
    })
  )
  .pipe(gulp.dest("./css"));
```

})
);

Do you have any idea about this?
Thank you.

Comment: You didn't list which editor you're facing this problem with

Comment: I'm using Visual Code.

Comment: Guess the full name is visual studio code?

Answer (score 1):

The TailwindCSS Intellisense plugin for VS code has an experimental setting that lets you set custom regex expressions that fire autocomplete. It's announced by the plugin's author here:
https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss-intellisense/issues/129#issuecomment-735915659

I use these 2 regular expressions to activate autocomplete for `{% set classes = [] }` and `<element{{ attributes.addClass() }}>` respectively:

```
"tailwindCSS.experimental.classRegex": [
   ["classes =.+\\[([^\\]]*)\\]","'([^']*)'"],
   ["addClass\\(([^\\)]*)\\)","'([^']*)'"]
]
```

This goes into the main settings.json file for VS Code.